# Returning inner $http promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have two services:

ProductService

CartService

And a Controller:

ShoppingController

ShoppingController needs to download the cart from the server. In order for CartService to do this, ProductService must first download the products.

ProductService.js

```
ProductService.DownloadProducts = function(){
          if(alreadyHaveDownloadedProducts){                   
              return {
                  success: function (fn) {
                      fn(products);
                  }
              };
          }else{
              if(getProductsPromise== null){
                  getProductsPromise= $http.post("Api/GetProducts")  
              }
              return getProductsPromise;
          }
```

CartService.js

```
CartService.DownloadCart = function(){
    ProductService.DownloadProducts().success(function(){
          if(alreadyHaveDownloadedCart){   
              //Dont need to go to server                
              return {
                  success: function (fn) {
                      fn(cart);
                  }
              };
          }else{
              if(getCartPromise == null){
                  getCartPromise = $http.post("Api/GetCart")  
              }
              return getCartPromise; //<= The promise I actually want to return
          }
    })
}
```

ProductService.DownloadProducts

ShoppingController.js

```
CartService.DownloadCart().success(function(){DisplayCart()});
```

This approach works nicely so far, because if the ProductService has already been called on a different page, I don't need to go back to the server. Same for cart service.The issue is I currently can't return the getCartPromise as it hasn't been created until the async GetProducts has returned

Is it possible to structure this so I can return the inner promise to ShoppingController while keeping the nice .success() syntax?

Comment: You could use `async/await` syntax to keep the code clean.

Comment: Pay attention that `DownloadCart` in returning void, not a promise.

Comment: felixmosh - correct, the question is how to return the inner promise

Answer (score 0):

My way is similar to yours, but instead of saving some `alreadyHaveDownloadedCart` (boolean flag), i'm caching the promise it self, and then returns it.

I'm caching the promise for the data on the service class, and then returning it if it is exists otherwise initialize a server call.

Something like that:

```
class ProductService {
  constructor() {
    this.productsPromise = null;
  }

  DownloadProducts() {
    if(!this.productsPromise) {
      this.productsPromise = $http.post('Api/GetProducts');

      this.productsPromise.then(products => this.products = products);
    }

    return this.productsPromise.then(() => this.products);
  }
}

class CartService {
  constructor(ProductService) {
    this.ProductService = ProductService;
    this.cartPromise = null;
  }

  DownloadCart() {
    return this.ProductService.DownloadProducts().success(() => {
      if (!this.cartPromise) {
        this.cartPromise = $http.post('Api/GetCart');
        this.cartPromise.then((cart) => {
          this.cart = cart;
        });
      }

      return this.cartPromise.then(() => this.cart);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this DownloadCart will return the result of .success which is void. It will not return the result of the function that is passed to .success (the lambda)

Comment: Success is a depricated api of promise that came from jquery, use then instead, which returns a new promise with the value that returns inside the callback